# How to implement WSS: X509 Token Profile 1.0 on a WCF Web Service (Server Side)

Tags: wcf, ws-security, x509

I'm newer at creating WCF web services and I'm trying to figure out how to create a WCF service that conforms to the WSS:X509 Token Profile 1.0.  There are many posts about how to do the client configuration however, not much about server configurations.

This project began as a WSDL-first generated service, so I am unable to change anything about how the client sends data to me, and I'm required to make the service conform to the data they send.

I've gone and created a custom endpoint for this service, however this is where i'm stuck.  I'm sure theres just some small detail i'm missing to make it conform to the pdf below:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0.pdf

```
    <behavior name="Something.ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <clientCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
          <certificate findValue="ClientCertificate" 
                       storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                       storeName="My" 
                       x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        </clientCertificate>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="OurCertificate" 
                            storeLocation="LocalMachine" 
                            storeName="My" 
                            x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
      <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application"
                            serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure"
                            messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure"
                            suppressAuditFailure="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>


  <service behaviorConfiguration="Something.ServiceName"
    name="Something.ServiceName">
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" name="MetaDataEndPoint" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding0" name="customBindingEndPoint" contract="Something.IServiceName" >
    </endpoint>


    <binding name="CustomBinding0">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11" />
      <httpTransport />
    </binding>
```

Any Help/Comments is greatly appreciated.